# Solr schema.xml changes not recognized by Solr

Tags: solr, plone

I recently made a tiny change in my `schema.xml` file. Basically the only thing I did was changing the stopwords file the StopFilter uses:

`<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />`

changed to

`<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_de.txt" />`

`stopwords_de.txt` is from the predefined set of stopwords provided by Solr.

However, my problem now is that the changes in the schema won't be applied even when I reindex. I checked the Solr Admin UI schema browser for this field and the StopFilter still uses the old stopwords file after reindexing.

**Do I need to reload my core or even restart Solr for these changes to apply? So far Reindexing did that job just fine.**

---

I am using the Collective Solr 4.1.0 Search on our Plone 4.2.6 system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restart the server. Also, have a look at the [documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#RELOAD) about reloading a core.

- `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=YourCoreName` to reload a core without restarting the server.

Please note that since Solr 4.0, does not reload everything (e.g. changes in `<dataDir>` are ignored). You can refer to [SOLR-3592](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3592) for more information on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

A simple restart of Solr did the job. As of this point, Solr uses the changed `schema.xml`. The change for the StopFilter works and I can check it in the UI's analyzer option.

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself facing this problem even if you are using a newer version of Solr (in my case 8.10), make sure to delete the file `<SOLR HOME>/server/solr/<your core>/conf/managed-schema` and restart the solr server. During the restart Solr will read the `schema.xml` file and create a new `managed-schema` file to reflect the changes.